# Unresolved reference in kotlin with id and activity_main

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm actually creating a new app in kotlin to display an xml file in boxes with the informations formatted

To problem is that when I'm building the app, there is the activity_main, the id that return "Unresolved reference"

```
Unresolved reference: id
Unresolved reference: id
```

Here the MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.instantsystem

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import java.io.IOException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val listView = findViewById<ListView>(id.listView)
        var employees: List<Employee>? = null
        try {
            val parser = XmlPullParserHandler()
            val istream = assets.open("employees.xml")
            employees = parser.parse(istream)

            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, employees)
            listView.adapter = adapter

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Here the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.instantsystem.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't understand the error, I imported the package and defined it in xml. What is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Have you tried `R.id.listView` ?

Comment: You are using androidX library inside Java code, but  in Xml you are using support library. Can you try changing `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` with `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Tried all the given solution that are given here, But didn't work. Then I tried to comment the latest code that I have added. Then this error gone like charm :)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

In my case removing `import android.R` solved the issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Any reason for this?

Comment: Same here. Removing `import android.R` solved this problem.

Comment: In my case this worked because I have a multi-module project.  I had copied some code from one module to another.  I copied the imports too.  But the imports referred to `R` that was specific to the source module.  So Android Studio went looking in the wrong module for the layout.  When I removed the import, Android Studio was able to find the layout.

Comment: Removing 'import android.R' also worked for me

Comment: Damn solid 2 hours wasted

Comment: Where is the `import android.R`?

Comment: usually first entry in file added automaticly during conversion.

Comment: Thanks, works. In my case, there was both "import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R" and "import com.[rest of my domain].R". Deleting first one helped.

Comment: Thanks. After I pasted Java code which got converted to Kotlin in Android Studio, `import android.R` was automatically added. So I removed it and it works fine.

Comment: Ditto. Pasted some code, was offered to convert to Kotlin... bang!! An hour wasted trying to figure it out. Back in business thanks to SkorpEn

Answer (score 28):

remove `import android.R` from imports which might be imported automatically.

Answer (score 11):

On newest verison `kotlin-android-extensions` needed to apply inside `build.gradle` (Module..)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Same as [@SkorpEN has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611875/unresolved-reference-in-kotlin-with-id-and-activity-main/60205538#60205538),
For me also removing **import android.R** solved the issue.

The reason why **import android.R** added from nowhere is, if you paste a java code into Kotlin it will convert to Kotlin automatically and some times this **import android.R** will also be added automatically.

Answer (score 6):

In my case; i edited the `MainActivity.kt` codes within automatic imports so I had to add:

```
import com.package.name.R
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I accidentally deleted the package declaration, so adding `package your.package.name` fixed it for me.

Comment: Just adding the comment for a very new android resource like myself for clarification: need to add this statement "package your.package.name" in the file (at the top) in the file that is causing the issue, where "your.package.name" can be found in AndroidManifest.xml file found in app > manifests.

Answer (score 3):

Using Kotlin Android Extensions, you don't need to call `findViewById()` anymore.
Just like that :

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var employees: List<Employee>? = null
        try {
            val parser = XmlPullParserHandler()
            val istream = assets.open("employees.xml")
            employees = parser.parse(istream)

            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, employees)
            listView.adapter = adapter  // here, the listView variable name refers to the id given in the xml file

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, in 2021, this was the right answer. You don't need `findByViewID` anymore, amazing! Just add that import at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting import Android.R will work most of the times as [mentioned by SkorpEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611875/unresolved-reference-in-kotlin-with-id-and-activity-main/60205538#60205538).

If you could not find that import, try checking the package name on top of the Activity. If there is no package name add the package name or if the name is already there try deleting the line and rewriting the name.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me after trying to rename my application name and packages and folders.
Make sure you search the code for all old names and replace them with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

there was no `import android.R` in my code to remove and
I had already declared my package in MainActivity.kt

Updating Android Gradle Plugin worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
val listView = findViewById<ListView>(id.listView)
```

to this

```
val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
```

you are missing R reference.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if the AndroidManifest.xml has the wrong package name.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the answers in this post, none of them worked for me, but I was able to fix it and it was very easy.

First I invalidated the cache, then I added this line

**import com.your.package.R;**

In my case I did not have any import with R, so I had to add it, for a moment I thought it was not a good solution but after reviewing and testing there was no problem, I hope you can solve your problem.

The version of Android Studio Electric Eel

macOS Ventura 13.2

Gradle 7.2.2

Answer (score 1):

This caused because of `Resource` or known as `R` wrong path. Find `**.**.R` in your imports class. delete it then import your project resources. For Example, in my case, i removed:

```
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R
```

changed it with

```
import my.package.name.R
```

Comment: There are no **.**.R imports in his code

Answer (score 0):

After failing on Rebuild Project and Make Project, finally Clean Project works for me. (Remember to add the plugin, `kotlin-android-extensions` beforehand.)

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the answers above worked for me, I found another solution that did work: prepend the package name to `R`.

For example, change from this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.llDirectionsButtonImageView)).perform(click())
```

To this:

```
onView(withId(com.myco.appsdk.R.id.llDirectionsButtonImageView)).perform(click())
```

In my case, the problem was happening in Espresso test code in a multi-module project.  One module, appsdk, contains all of the UI code and resource files.  Another module, app, creates an `Application` based on the appsdk and runs Espresso tests on that application.  For this reason, I think the Espresso test code in the app module needs to refer to the resource ids in the appsdk with a fully-qualified name.  For years, I didn't need to add the prefix.  I think a recent dependency upgrade may have made it a requirement to add the prefix.

Here are some relevant version numbers of dependencies/environment I'm using:

- Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1
- macOS 12.4
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
- classpath
  "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
- androidTestImplementation
  "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.3.0"
- androidTestImplementation
  "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0"
- implementation
  "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0"
- androidTestImplementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1"

Answer (score 0):

I know it is older post, but in my case the solution was to import:

```
**import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.your_activity.* **
```

It is imported automatically if you write a part of your id of `TextView` and select it from the list which is shown in Android Studio

Be sure you have this plugin mentioned above:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

After inserting it, execute the Sync action.

Answer (score 0):

I love such classic Android Studio Issues. Hahaha!

I removed `android.R` import, it fixed itself. And interestingly, my `menu_main.xml` got changed reference in the `MainActivity` as `main_menu`.

I simply asked the IDE, it created a new file `main_menu.xml`, I don't know what is going on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For my, Android Studio added out of nowhere the import:
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R
I had to manually remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Reading the different cases of the developers you see the average of the problem, and if you properly review the documentation in the community you find the solution that focuses on meeting the programming standards
check:

- https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-widgets-005.html
- https://developer.android.com/build/configure-app-module?hl=es-419#groovy

Rest assured that by applying this you will better solve your problem and understand why something happens, happy code.